# Should there be solder mask under this QFN-16 chip?

Tags: solder-mask

The layout for a QFN-16 packaged chip (FXOS8700CQ) I am using is shown below.

I'm confused about the solder mask opening. Should it be everywhere inside the green outline or just rectangles around the pads? The first method results in exposed FR4 in the middle.

Will it matter either way?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Better to minimize the size of the openings, to prevent solder shorts underneath the IC. This kind of package is very difficult for visual inspection.

Comment: Are you sure that the part that you are using does not have a thermal pad on the bottom of the package? Edit a link to the part data sheet into your question.

Comment: The solder mask arrow is pointing to the *red* rectangles, not the green one. The *green* one would be a minimal keep out.

Comment: @FRob It is the green one, see extra pic I just added.

Comment: Whoa, that is weird... Go with a regular solder mask then to avoid shorts under the IC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There should be no solder mask under the chip, no.  As it states in the datasheet:

> The purpose is to minimize the stress on the package after board mounting.

These are very sensitive devices.  I mean, you're not even supposed to have any components within 2mm of them.

Solder mask goes over the top of the copper.  The solder goes on the copper.  Surface tension sucks the chip down towards the copper (unless you have lots of excess solder).  With the solder mask in there as well it could cause stress on the package as it tries to get sucked down by the solder to a lower level than the solder mask.

By not having the solder mask you're removing that extra stress from the equation.

True, there may be absolutely no contact between the chip and the solder mask anyway, but with such sensitive devices, and with mass production (and the associated required low failure rate) the intended build environment, everything they can do to remove the possibility of extra stresses is important.

So you can use it with a solder mask, but if you want full reliability and repeatability, then you shouldn't have a solder mask.

Comment: The chip is an accelerometer / magnetometer so this makes sense.

Comment: I've use accelerometers like this, and followed the guidelines, and I have to say that following the directions and omitting the solder mask gives me a high failure rate even when using a stencil using prototyping techniques for reflow.  I've often considered posting question on how to get this right.

Comment: @ScottSeidman yeah this is a pita package for anyone to do.  I don't see how you could get it right repeatedly without accurate pick and place, the exact right stencil aperture and thickness, perfect lift off, paste viscosity etc.  it would for sure be something you'd struggle to dial in at production time.